# Subversion client hook doesn't show echo

Tags: batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn

This is my precommit hook. When I start a commit, my external diff tool does pops up, but the cmd window shows nothing, and it doesn't read my keyboard input.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq" %%i IN (%1) DO (svn diff %%i >nul)
echo hello
choice /M "Continue to commit?" 
SET userChoice=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %userChoice% equ 1 exit /b 0
IF %userChoice% equ 2 exit /b 1
```

[image: My subversion configuration]

Did I miss anything?

Comment: As per the [help documentation of TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) you need to do **explicit redirection to the console (device `con`)**, like `echo Checking Status > con` or `pause < con > con`...

Comment: @aschipfl `choice /M "Continue to commit?" < con > con` gives error: ERROR: The handle is invalid.

Comment: I never ever did that with the `choice` command, I only used `> con echo` and `pause < con > con` for debugging, which works; you could also try using `< con > con set /P`...

Comment: @aschipfl What I need is to let user confirm if he wants to continue the commit. What other methods can I use?

Comment: I meant to use `set /P` just for checking whether the `con` redirection works; for confirmation I would use another language, like JavaScript or VBScript, where you have the possibility to create a Yes/No or OK/Cancel message box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [help documentation of TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) you need to do explicit redirection to the console (device `con`):

> When debugging hook scripts you may want to echo progress lines to the DOS console, or insert a pause to stop the console window disappearing when the script completes. Because I/O is redirected this will not normally work. However you can redirect input and output explicitly to CON to overcome this. e.g.
>
> ```
> echo Checking Status > con
> pause < con > con
> ```

Unfortunately, this does not work with the `choice` command as it does not seem to accept input redirected from device `con`:

> ```
> >>> choice < con
> ERROR: The handle is invalid.
> ```

---

A simple work-around is to use the `set /P` command which does support redirection from `con`:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Loop structure for prompting user:
:CONFIRM
rem // Display prompt and await user input:
< con > con set /P SELECT="Continue? [Yes/No]?"
rem // Check user input case-insensitively:
if /I "%SELECT%"=="Y"   exit /B 0
if /I "%SELECT%"=="Yes" exit /B 0
if /I "%SELECT%"=="N"   exit /B 1
if /I "%SELECT%"=="No"  exit /B 1
rem // Repeat prompt in case of invalid entry:
goto :CONFIRM

endlocal
exit /B
```

The disadvantage of this is that the entry needs to be terminated with <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, in contrast to the `choice` command, which accepts a single-key input.

---

Here is a better approach which features a single-key prompt similar to the `choice` command. This (mis-)uses the `xcopy` command and its ability to accept redirected input into the copy confirmation prompt that appears when the `/W` switch is supplied. Take also a look at the explanatory remarks:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Loop structure for prompting user:
:CONFIRM
rem // Display prompt without trailing line-break:
< nul > con set /P ="Continue? [Y/N]?"
rem /* Let `xcopy` wait for a single-key entry using its `/W` switch;
rem    `/L` tells `xcopy` to actually copy nothing; to avoid problems
rem    with inexistent paths, use this script's path as source file
rem    and the system's temporary directory as the target location: */
< con (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
        xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%TMP%\"
    ') do (
        rem /* Capture the copy confirmation prompt of `xcopy /L /W`,
        rem    `Press any key when ready to begin copying file(s)`,
        rem    together with the character entered by the user, which
        rem    is appended to the prompt message: */
        set "CHAR=%%L"
        rem /* Leave loop upon first iteration, because we are not
        rem    interested in any copying results and summaries: */
        goto :SKIP
    )
)
:SKIP
rem // Extract the last character, which is the actual user input:
set "CHAR=!CHAR:~-1!"
rem // Display user entry:
> con echo(!CHAR!
rem // Check user input case-insensitively:
if /I "!CHAR!"=="Y" exit /B 0
if /I "!CHAR!"=="N" exit /B 1
rem // Repeat prompt in case of invalid entry:
goto :CONFIRM

endlocal
exit /B
```

If an unexpected input is provided, the prompt is reprinted on the next line and new user input is awaited.

---

To avoid reprinting the prompt text in case of unexpected user input, use the following script:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "MESSAGE=Confirm? [Y/N]?"

rem // Retrieve back-space character:
for /F %%Z in ('prompt $H ^& for %%Z in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "BS=%%Z"
rem // Retrieve carriage-return character:
for /F %%Z in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%Z"

rem // Loop structure for prompting user:
:CONFIRM
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Display prompt without trailing line-break:
> con < nul set /P ="%BS%  !CR!!MESSAGE!"
endlocal
rem /* Let `xcopy` wait for a single-key entry using its `/W` switch;
rem    `/L` tells `xcopy` to actually copy nothing; to avoid problems
rem    with inexistent paths, use this script's path as source file
rem    and the system's temporary directory as the target location: */
< con (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
        xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%TMP%\"
    ') do (
        rem /* Capture the copy confirmation prompt of `xcopy /L /W`,
        rem    `Press any key when ready to begin copying file(s)`,
        rem    together with the character entered by the user, which
        rem    is appended to the prompt message: */
        set "CHAR=%%L"
        rem /* Leave loop upon first iteration, because we are not
        rem    interested in any copying results and summaries: */
        goto :SKIP
    )
)
:SKIP
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Extract the last character, which is the actual user input:
set "CHAR=!CHAR:~-1!"
rem // Display user entry without trailing line-break:
> con < nul set /P ="!CHAR!"
rem // Check user input case-insensitively:
if /I "!CHAR!"=="Y" exit /B 0
if /I "!CHAR!"=="N" exit /B 1
endlocal
rem // Repeat prompt in case of invalid entry:
goto :CONFIRM
echo/

endlocal
exit /B
```

This is a comprehensive solution that allows usage of special characters like `!`, `^` and `"` too.

---

Here is a quite similar solution relying on the `replace` command, together with its `/W` switch, also without reprinting the prompt in case of unexpected user input. Since `replace` prints the character of the key-press in a separate line, there is no need to split it off of another string (opposed to `xcopy /W`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "MESSAGE=Confirm? [Y/N]?"

rem // Retrieve back-space character:
for /F %%Z in ('prompt $H ^& for %%Z in ^(.^) do rem/') do set "BS=%%Z"
rem // Retrieve carriage-return character:
for /F %%Z in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%Z"

rem // Loop structure for prompting user:
:CONFIRM
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Display prompt without trailing line-break:
> con < nul set /P ="%BS%  !CR!!MESSAGE!"
endlocal
rem /* Let `replace` wait for a single-key entry using its `/W` switch;
rem    `/U` tells `replace` to actually do nothing; to avoid problems
rem    with inexistent paths, use this script's path as source file
rem    and its parent directory as the target location: */
< con (
    for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%L in ('
        replace /W /U "%~f0" "."
    ') do (
        rem /* Capture the confirmation user input of `replace /W /U`,
        rem    skipping the prompt `Press any key to continue . . .`: */
        set "CHAR=%%L"
        rem /* Leave loop upon first iteration, because we are not
        rem    interested in any replacement results and summaries: */
        goto :SKIP
    )
)
:SKIP
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Display user entry without trailing line-break:
> con < nul set /P ="!CHAR!"
rem // Check user input case-insensitively:
if /I "!CHAR!"=="Y" exit /B 0
if /I "!CHAR!"=="N" exit /B 1
endlocal
rem // Repeat prompt in case of invalid entry:
goto :CONFIRM
echo/

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: thank you very much! Batch is so complicated and non-uniform.